# Change bibliography style in text within aastex

Tags: natbib, aastex

I want to use the `aastex` style for an overleaf document, but I need to change the bibliography style, such that the references are indicated in the text as `this is the references [1]` and in the bibliography can mantain the standard `\bibliographystyle{aasjournal}`.
I have read that I can get something similar by using `\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}`.

However, if I simply try to compile

```
\documentclass{aastex63}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
```

it returns a conflict error:

```
 LaTeX Error: Option clash for package natbib.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4 

The package natbib has already been loaded with options:
  [sort&compress]
There has now been an attempt to load it with options
  [square,numbers]
Adding the global options:
  sort&compress,square,numbers
to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
```

Now, if I go to the `aastex63.cls` document, I only find two entries related to `natbib` and this problem:

```
% Restore natbib package without sorting. 
\def\NAT@sort{0}
\def\NAT@cmprs{0}

% only redefine sort@cites for natbib versions < 2009
\@ifundefined{NAT@sort@cites@}{\def\NAT@sort@cites#1{\edef\NAT@cite@list{#1}}}%
```

I thought it was enough to comment out the first two of these lines, but this is evidently wrong. Any advice?

Comment: Hi, I work for the AAS Journals. This might be better handled on https://github.com/AASJournals/AASTeX60, but why do you need AASTeX and numbered rather than Author (Year) citations? This isn't a supported use case.

Comment: @Gus, thank you. Dual-anonymous asks for that. I do not have a github account. Can I still post there?

Comment: Do you mean dual-anonymous for PSJ? I am unaware of that requirement! Can you provide a link? And yes, you would need a github account to post there. This is fine though. If there's a deep issue we can't fix then I'll post an issue so we can keep track of it.

Comment: It is a proposal that requires dual-anonymous. Not a journal publication.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Again, I'm not sure that this is a supported use case (numbered references) since we have formally adopted Author (Year) style. If there is a proposal system that is requiring you to use AASTeX6+ and aasjournal.bst then please let me know. I think that the deeper problem is that AASTeX wraps revtex, which prevents passing natbib options all the way into it. But honestly I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\usepackage{natbib}

\setcitestyle{square}

\renewcommand\bibnumfmt[1]{[#1] }
```